# save the image in the clipboatd - in Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

the subject says it all: is it possible to take an image present in the clipboard and save it to file under Tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that should get let you get arbitrary clipboard data on windows.

```
import win32clipboard as clip

# The standard windows clipboard formats
formats = ['CF_OEMTEXT', 'CF_PALETTE', 'CF_TEXT', 'CF_ENHMETAFILE', 'CF_UNICODETEXT', 
            'CF_BITMAP', 'CF_METAFILEPICT', 'CF_DIB', 'CF_DIBV5']

def getFromClipboard(format):
    '""Returns a given type of data from the clipboard.'
    data = None
    clip.OpenClipboard(0)
    if clip.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(format):
        data = clip.GetClipboardData(format)
    clip.CloseClipboard()
    return data

good_formats = []
clip.OpenClipboard(0)
for format in formats:
    if clip.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(format):
        good_formats.append(format)
clip.CloseClipboard()

# choose among the good formats here
print good_formats

# use the one you picked here
data = getFromClipboard(good_formats[0])
```

Then `data` will be the raw image data and you can just save it to a file normally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32clipboard__GetClipboardData_meth.html

Provide some information, more is out there.

Comment: ouch, I needed it for the complement Os'es: Linux & OSX !

Comment: I didn't see any way to get non-text clipboard data on posix systems.

Comment: No -- it sounds like it'll work, but I don't know how to get the dimensions or anything like that.

Comment: may/may not help: http://www.effbot.org/zone/pil-image-size.htm and http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2004-September/002955.html

Comment: @noob oddy: the 1st link not so much, but I had many hopes from the 2nd: my prog uses ImageMagick a lot. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to convince `import` to use the clipboard as input

Comment: I think that thread he links suggests that it creates a temporary file called tempfile.ppm, have you looked for that?

Comment: @agf: yes, but he says it _maybe_ could be done so by IM's Import. Problem is it doesnt seem to me that Import can read from clipboard

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isn't he saying the _clipboard_ is automatically saved as a temp file when it's image data, so ImageMagic just has to read that, it doesn't have to __know it's the clipboard__, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Well tkinter uses the PIL for most of its advanced image stuff, in which case this problem is quite simple: Just use `Image.frombuffer(mode, size, data)` with the bytebuffer representing the image and then save it ala `im.save(filename)`- if you want a special format you can also specify it.

If you want to do it without the PIL, I don't think tkinter offers that kind of functionality out of the box, its image support is extremely limited in itself.

Comment: this seems to be it! But I tried using it without luck with 
      `wx,wy = 3000,3000
    buf = "a"*wx*wy
    im=Image.frombuffer("L", (wx, wy), buf, "raw", "L", 0, 1)`
      ... my problem is that I dont know how to know in advance the image size (nor the mode) of the image in the clipboard