# X11 Wait for and Get Clipboard Text

Tags: c, x11

I have to monitor the X11 Clipboard.

For the moment, I request the ClipBoard Selection each 5 seconds, then I hash the text returned from clipboard and I compare it with the hash calculate from the last check. If hash are not the same, I analysis the text content and do some stuff...

I don't like my method. I'm from Windows, and with the winapi, it is the kernel that notify your program when the clipboard has changed, and it's more efficient!

I just want to know if it is possible that X11 can notify your program as winapi when the clipboard has changed ? What is the more efficient way to check clipboard modifications with X11 ?

Answer (score 15):

Use `XFixesSelectSelectionInput()` from **Xfixes** extension and wait for `XFixesSelectionNotify` event.

Example:

```
// gcc -o xclipwatch xclipwatch.c -lX11 -lXfixes
...
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>
...
void WatchSelection(Display *display, Window window, const char *bufname)
{
  int event_base, error_base;
  XEvent event;
  Atom bufid = XInternAtom(display, bufname, False);

  assert( XFixesQueryExtension(display, &event_base, &error_base) );
  XFixesSelectSelectionInput(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), bufid, XFixesSetSelectionOwnerNotifyMask);

  while (True)
  {
    XNextEvent(display, &event);

    if (event.type == event_base + XFixesSelectionNotify &&
        ((XFixesSelectionNotifyEvent*)&event)->selection == bufid)
    {
      if (!PrintSelection(display, window, bufname, "UTF8_STRING"))
        PrintSelection(display, window, bufname, "STRING");

      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }
}
...
```

This works both for `bufname == "CLIPBOARD"` and `bufname == "PRIMARY"` selection.

Also see `PrintSelection()` function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992938/8277616).

Comment: Please do not put mandatory commands into `assert()`, [because `assert()` leaves the impression that it can be left away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) (see `NDEBUG`). Better: `int xfixinstalled = XFixesQueryExtension(display, &event_base, &error_base); assert(xfixinstalled);`

Comment: I seem to be missing X11/extensions/xfixes.h in my Ubuntu 20.04 - any idea where I can find it? Is it something that has to be installed? I only see xfixesproto.h

Comment: @tofutim I did `apt-file search Xfixes.h`. It told me I needed to install `libxfixes-dev` so I did and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find window with selection using `GetSelectionOwner` (PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD)
2. get copy of selection by sending SelectionRequest, notify your application
3. watch for `SelectionClear` event
4. update window with selection using id from `SelectionClear` event, goto step 2

Comment: What do you do when the selection owner is closed?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from x11user is a good one. But you probably want a non-blocking while loop, and for that you can take that answer, and adapt it like this.

```
// get the internal X11 event file descriptor
int x11fd = ConnectionNumber(display);

while(!shutdown)
{
  if(!XPending(display)) {
    // wait on the file descriptor
    // you can use poll, epoll, select, eventfd, etc.
  }

  XNextEvent(display, &event);
  // process the event
}
```