# keeping track of copy-paste in x11 using clipboard

Tags: linux, clipboard, copy-paste, x11

I'm a newbie to x11. As part of my final project, i have to keep track of all copy paste's in a single machine(from which window to which window) using clipboard in linux X window system. For that i think i need to work with open source x11. But i completely don't know where to start. Which module of x11 should i deal with, to handle the inter-client communication of the x window system. http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/src/

If possible please provide me some good source for developers in inter-client communications of x11. I found so many docs in x.org, but nothing is clearly given regarding the implementation.

Comment: The copy & paste action is not implemented by the x11 base. It is application specific. So probably your best approach is to take a closer look at clipboard implementations and extend one to log all actions.

Comment: @arkascha yes, my idea is to log all actions of clipboard. But where exactly this clipboard is implemented and what should i refer for that. Can i have the details if you are aware..?

Comment: The clipboard is an ordinary application you have installed. So the question is: which clipboard are you using, then you have the answer where it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Cut-and-paste in X11 is based on window properties and selections. [This](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) is a very good intro to X11 paste buffers/clipboards/selections. Read about associated selections/properties, then use XSelectInput and monitor [property](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/client-communication/property.html)/[selection](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/client-communication/selection.html) changes.

#### See also:

[X11 Get Clipboard Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755471/x11-get-clipboard-text)

Comment: To monitor and log these copy-pastes, do I need to modify any open-source code or it can be done with x11 APIs itself?

Comment: by X11 api you mean xlib? Yes, you can do it with xlib