# How to monitor clipboard changes in X11 Windows?

Tags: c++, c, linux, clipboard, x11

I am pretty much exhausted all the possibilities of finding an X11 API to perform the following thing.

I have a thread which is trying to monitor for an event or notification to know when anything is copied into clipboard by any X11 `client`. I do not want to monitor a specific Atom Target (clipboard format), but generally looking for changes in clipboards.

Once, I know that something has changed in the clipboard, I can dive in and perform `XConvertSelection()` on all the target formats (I want to request `server` to give me all the possible ways to convert the copied data), and futher process them into `SelectionRequest` event.

Again, I want to generally get request for all the formats (thinking to enumerate between 1 to 1000 to check target Atoms), and not register changes for one specific format. Based on response from the server, if a particular atom is absent, I can check `None` as the property member, or else store other target Atom Names in a list.

Can anyone help me with how to monitor for changes in Clipboard? Also, does iterating 1 to 1000 will guarantee exhaustive search of all possible format? Or is there a better way to do just that?

Comment: Related [keeping track of copy-paste in x11 using clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18825483/3422102) and perhaps [X11: How does “the” clipboard work?](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To monitor changes, use [XFixes](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/fixesproto/fixesproto.txt). With XCB it is used like:

```cpp
// Enable XFixes
auto xfixes = xcb_get_extension_data(connection, &xcb_xfixes_id); // do not free!
ev_selection_change_notify = xfixes->first_event + XCB_XFIXES_SELECTION_NOTIFY;
auto *version = xcb_xfixes_query_version_reply(xcb_xfixes_query_version(connection, XCB_XFIXES_MAJOR_VERSION, XCB_XFIXES_MINOR_VERSION));

// Subscribe to clipboard notifications
xcb_xfixes_select_selection_input(connection, root, clipboard, XCB_XFIXES_SELECTION_EVENT_MASK_SET_SELECTION_OWNER);

// Event loop:
auto *event = xcb_poll_for_event(connection);
int etype = event->response_type & 0x7f;
if (etype == ev_selection_change_notify) {
    auto *notification = reinterpret_cast<xcb_xfixes_selection_notify_event_t *>(event);
    ...
}
...
```

In Xlib it should be similar.

To check the list of available targets, don’t loop to 1000! Simply query the `TARGETS` target, it should give you the list of valid targets for the clipboard content.

There is a caveat, though: instead of “the” clipboard, X11 allow applications to use “selections” which can be tagged by arbitrary atoms. Of those `CLIPBOARD` is of primary interest but `PRIMARY` and (rarely used) `SECONDARY` are also there, as well as arbitrary selections for “private communication”.

Reference: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/icccm/icccm.html#Use_of_Selection_Atoms

Comment: Query the TARGETS target, to get the list of valid targets. Which API are you referring to?

Comment: `XConvertSelection`. TARGETS is one of targets (formats) you can request, like STRING or whatever. See [this section](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/icccm/icccm.html#Target_Atoms) for details.