# How to copy clipboard data when clipboard event triggers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard

My goal is to copy clipboard data (text or bmp) while clipboard event triggers. Events I am interested in:

1. Listen SelectionRequest & SelectionNotify, SelectionClear etc..
2. when Event triggers, go to clipboard and read it's data out.

But if I use `XSetSelectionOwner`, the event can be capture, but I took over everything, so the original behavior is not happen, for an example, if i use `XSetSelectionOwner` and press mouse right key, the "Copy"/"Paste" pop up window will not pop anymore, so I cannot listen what it happen.

Is there a method, i can just "listen" when clipboard event happens, without override it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755471/x11-get-clipboard-text
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755471/x11-get-clipboard-text)

Comment: used GTK library instead (Ubuntu16.04)