# Monitor the actions of copy and paste in Linux

Tags: linux, x11

**scenario：** We often copy and paste texts or images when using Linux OS (like Ubuntu), such as copy texts from one editor to another one.

**questions**:

1. How to use higher level programming language, like shell/perl/others,instead of c/c++ to do with kernel or X11 to solve this problem?

Thanks.

PS: The question is different from [X11 Wait for and Get Clipboard Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755471/x11-wait-for-and-get-clipboard-text).

Comment: @ tk421 Thanks for your suggestion, but I wanna know if we can solve this by shell script.

Comment: Did you look at `xsel`?  https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel

Comment: @tk421, this would be helpful, thanks.