# How the X application can detect that the selection owner changed?

Tags: linux, gtk, xserver

I am playing with the X protocol and noticed, that when my program sends `SetSelectionOwner`, several other clients instantly send to me `SelectionRequest` events with target `TARGETS`.

But how they know that the selection owner has been changed? There is no such event in the X specification.

Do they all the time poll the server with `GetSelectionOwner` requests?

Or there is another, event based mechanism that I missed in the documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755471/x11-wait-for-and-get-clipboard-text

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it is XFIXES extension that introduces selection tracking events. Thanks.