# python:on linux os how to save clipboard as image

Tags: python-3.x, linux, python-imaging-library

I want to convert clipboard image content into an image

I tried

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save(filename)
```

it says `ImageGrab.grabclipboard() is macOS and Windows only`

Comment: An expression like `im = foo() is x` will make `im` a boolean btw. Not sure booleans have a save method. Plus thinking maybe there is some missing quotations in sample code. Assuming its `"macOS and Windows only"` then I'm pretty sure `im` is gonna be `False`. Either way, its clear this will not do what you are thinking.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire clearly it's just a mistake where they accidentally pasted the error message in the code.

Comment: Simple Google search shows that this is a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841532/linux-image-from-clipboard/27995840

Comment: i tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12122028/2897115. i get `No module named gtk`. I am not sure anything changed since 2012 (the question was answered) and now

Comment: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: currnetly i solved this using `xclip` and `os.system`

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have to use xclip to solve this problem

it will try to save image from clipboard and if not it will return 1

```
    import os
    if os.system(f"xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -out > {filename}") == 0:
        print("save")
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```