# In Google Colab, how to accept an image input from clipboard and save it as a file?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, clipboard

I have an OCR pipeline set up, but it currently only works by uploading a file from file explorer.

`def upload_files(): from google.colab import files from io import BytesIO uploaded = files.upload() return [(name, BytesIO(b)) for name, b in uploaded.items()]`

`imgs = upload_files() predictions = [] for name, f in imgs: img = Image.open(f) math = model(img) print(math) predictions.append('\\mathrm{%s} & \\displaystyle{%s}'%(name, math)) Math(table%'\\\\'.join(predictions))`

The second code-block brings up a button to open file explorer and select the desired file to upload.

I would like to replace upload_files() as it is with something that accepts image input from clipboard by Ctrl+V when I run the second code block.

1. I've tried using Pillow with the code:
    `def upload_files(): from PIL import ImageGrab from io import BytesIO uploaded = ImageGrab.grabclipboard() return [(name, BytesIO(b)) for name, b in uploaded.items()]`

but it doesn't work and throws up an error:

`NotImplementedError: wl-paste or xclip is required for ImageGrab.grabclipboard() on Linux`

Neither wl-paste and xclip are Python projects so are not supported in Colab.

2. I've tried running the script here:
   [linux image from clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841532/linux-image-from-clipboard)
   https://gist.github.com/orschiro/8b9a1ddadb696c2b4587#file-image-clipboard-to-file-py

but it gives me errors.

Any suggestions?

Side-note: Apologies in advance if my question is lacking in some essential due diligence such as formatting, this is my first question here and I'm figuring out as I go along. Thanks!